# Unable to parse SOAP response

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I am using JAX-WS to call a SOAP webservice. While parsing a SOAP response getting below exception. My SOAP client is a JAR which is running inside another web application deployed in Weblogic server.

```
javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Error parsing envelope: most likely due to an invalid SOAP message.: Unexpected EOF in prolog
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0] 
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:677) 
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2139) 
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2045) 
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134) 
at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.util.ResettableXMLStreamReader.next(ResettableXMLStreamReader.java:218) 
at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.StaxHandler.moveNext(StaxHandler.java:213) 
at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.StaxHandler.staxParse(StaxHandler.java:117) 
at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.StaxHandler.staxParse(StaxHandler.java:105) 
at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.StaxHandler.staxParse(StaxHandler.java:88) 
at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.AbstractSOAPImplementation.getStaXParsedEnvelope(AbstractSOAPImplementation.java:235) 
at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.AbstractSOAPImplementation.createEnvelope(AbstractSOAPImplementation.java:70)
```

Surprisingly I am able to print the SOAP response in the logs.

Comment: So what's the SOAP response you have printed?

Comment: Sorry but can not reveal the entire soap envelop here due to confidentiality issue. But its a well formed message conforming SOAP xml standards.